# Custom image/HDRI background for solid/wireframe shading modes

Tags: 3d-view, world

I have a scene where using the *X-Ray* feature of the *Solid / Wireframe* shading modes is essential to my modelling process, however, I need to see the background HDRI as well.

*Material Preview* and *Rendered* shading modes do not allow for the use of the *X-Ray* modes, and even if I go into *Edit mode*, I do not get the same see-through effect that *Solid / Wireframe X-Ray* gives. And I didn't find a way to show the world background in *Solid / Wireframe* shading modes.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this, in *Material Preview*:

Of course enable the *Scene World* option in the *Viewport Shading* in order to see it when you are in *Material Preview*:

[image]

To see a transparent wire in *Object* mode, choose *Display As > Wire*:

[image]

To see a transparent wire in *Edit* mode, enable *Viewport Overlays > Hidden Wire*:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks!